# Enter KeyEvent behavior for Android IMEs

Tags: android, keyevent, ime

I have a custom implemented IME that sends KeyEvents when ImageButtons are pressed. When the ImageButton labeled Enter is pressed, the following code is executed:

```
ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0,0,MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER,0,0,0,0,KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION));
```

The problem is that underlying applications behave differently when Enter is pressed. In Messages, the text committed is sent, but in Browser and in editable fields, the last word typed is highlighted and options to cut and paste pop-up.

I'd like the Enter key to behave in such a way that works for "Go", "Send" and "Next".

Comment: Please use only the relevant tags. Read their descriptions by hovering your mouse over them.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

If you would like to enter "DONE" and "NEXT", use

```
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
KeyEvent eventDOWN  = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
 KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER, 0, 0,
 KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0,
 KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE
 | KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION);

KeyEvent eventUP = new KeyEvent(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), eventTime,
 KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER, 0, 0,
 KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0,
 KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE
 | KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION);
```